# Mongoose updating a document by removing a single object from document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can't find a solution for it :(

I'm doing a contacts app using Node, express and mongoose.

when a user goes to the route /contact/:id

this query gets executed:

```
Contact.findOne(req.dbQuery, function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```

The Response is:

```
 {
     _id: 57 d71ceb57658ba24866a1b0,
     __v: 0,
     firstName: ['Doe', 'text'],
     lastName: ['John', 'text'],
     id: 4,
     homePhone: ['', 'tel'],
     cellPhone: ['', 'tel'],
     birthday: ['', 'date'],
     website: ['', 'url'],
     address: ['test Adress', 'text'],
 }
```

Each item in the array is getting displayed on the page as a label and a textbox

using ng-repeat.

Next to each textbox I have an X button to remove a textbox.

On each X button there's ng-click="remove(field)"

```
$scope.remove = function(field){ //field can be 'homePhone' or any item 
     delete $scope.record[field];
     $scope.record.$update(function(updatedRecord){
         $scope.record = updatedRecord;
       }) 
     };
```

Problem is, When I'm clicking on the X button and calling

remove('homePhone') (or any of the fields - 'cellPhone' or any other)

i'm sending the correct data to the server via req.body (I can see the data

without the removed field) but getting a response including the field I just

removed.

On the server I'm executing:

```
Contact.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: contact._id
}, req.body, {
    upsert: true,
    new: true
}, function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```

I also have an "add new field" button that is adding a textbox by adding an item

to the array. I'm executing the same query on add new field

This is why I use {upsert: true, new: true}

Will I have to change everything?

Thanks a lot

Comment: how are you getting 'contact' in your findOneAndUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

please use `$unset` operator to remove any field from the document. that is the preferred way or removing fields from document when performing an update.

Comment: I tried to $unset a field but it doesn't completely removing it. The key still stay on the document.
I'm iterating with ng-repeat over the keys and present them as a label for the text box. I need to delete the object completely